# Copy formula and formatting

Tags: vba

How can i make the bellow only copy the Formula and formatting not the text?

```
Sub Loop_InsertRowsandFormulas()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Input Sheet")
Dim vRows As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim firstRow As Long

firstRow = InputBox("Enter Row To Start Insert From.")
vRows = InputBox("Enter Number Of Rows Required")

If firstRow = 0 Or vRows = 0 Then Exit Sub
Debug.Print firstRow
IngA = ws.Cells(5, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For Myloop = 1 To vRows
    ws.Range("A" & (firstRow + Myloop)).EntireRow.Insert
    ws.Range("N" & (firstRow) & ":AW" & (firstRow + Myloop)).FillDown
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    For Each ShipWs In ShipmentWbObj.Worksheets
    If ShipWs.name <> "SAMPLE_FORMAT" And ShipWs.name <> "Transportercodes" Then
        Set ShipWsUsedrange = ShipWs.UsedRange
        Set DataRange = Application.Intersect(ShipWsUsedrange, ShipWsUsedrange.Offset(1, 0))
        If Not DataRange Is Nothing Then
            SampleFormat.Rows(2).Copy
            DataRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
            DataRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, False, False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Endif
    Endif
Next
```

Comment: The sheet is not the best formatted in the world which has led us to the Macro we are using.  We need to be able to select where the new row is inputted then it will copy all the formula and formatting from above.  I can seen you a screen print if i new how too.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Would adding a .delete into the last line of code work?  So it then deletes the text in Column. S, V, W, X, Y, Z, AB, AD, AF, AI, AJ, AK of the new inserted row?